# Numerical value for days of the week

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2013

I need to write a formula in Excel that returns a numerical value in B1 for a day of the week entered in A1. For example:

`A1=Sun` so `B1=0;`
`A1=Mon` so `B1=1;`
`A1=Tues` so `B1=2;` etc.

I've set up a drop-down in A1 to keep the data consistent. I tried writing a nest IF and OR function in B1, but can't seem to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please select a correct answer to the left if one has been provided, else please clarify your question

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
 =MATCH(A1,{"Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"},0)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a lookup table (maybe where you dropdown data is) and use vlookup

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Dates!$A$1:$B$3,2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Type this code into cell B1.

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat";0,1,2,3,4,5,6})
```

Then you can copy it down the column as needed.

Comment: Please select a correct answer to the left if one has been provided, else please clarify your question